# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, rails-activestorage

I am getting this error while running active storage migration.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object: CREATE TABLE "ACTIVE_STORAGE_BLOBS" ("ID" NUMBER(38) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "KEY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, "CONTENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(255), "METADATA" CLOB, "BYTE_SIZE" NUMBER(19) NOT NULL, "CHECKSUM" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, "CREATED_AT" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
```

Here is the active storage Migration File that is using to create active storage blob and active storage attachments table

```
# This migration comes from active_storage (originally 20170806125915)
class CreateActiveStorageTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
  create_table :active_storage_blobs do |t|
    t.string   :key,        null: false
    t.string   :filename,   null: false
    t.string   :content_type
    t.text     :metadata
    t.bigint   :byte_size,  null: false
    t.string   :checksum,   null: false
    t.datetime :created_at, null: false

    t.index [ :key ], unique: true
  end

  create_table :active_storage_attachments do |t|
    t.string     :name,     null: false
    t.references :record,   null: false, polymorphic: true, index: false
    t.references :blob,     null: false

    t.datetime :created_at, null: false

    t.index [ :record_type, :record_id, :name, :blob_id ], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
    t.foreign_key :active_storage_blobs, column: :blob_id
  end
 end
end
```

System configuration

```
Rails version: 5.2.0
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter: 5.2.0 
ruby-oci8: 2.2.6.1
Ruby version: 2.6.0
Oracle Database version: 10.2.0.1.0
```

Comment: Oracle 10.2 ?? You are using a relatively new java framework with a very very old version of Oracle. It has nothing to do with the error  -you have an object with the same name in the schema you are trying to run the create table statement- , but you should think in using a newer version of Oracle.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, yes you are right to object is present with the same name in the schema, but My question is why it's happening again because I already run all the migrations. after updating ruby from 5.1 to 5.2 and then running Rspec get migration missing error and then run migration command got this error.

Comment: are you sure when run the migration again, that the objects are dropped ? or that you are creating two objects with the same name ( like a table and a view )

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I am creating only a single object with this name, have only one file for active storage

Comment: did you try to drop all tables in that schema before run the migration ? I guess you are connecting to the database with the same user as the schema owner of those tables, right ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez after dropping all tables it's working now

Comment: great, then issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Error says that **object** (not necessarily *table*) whose name is `ACTIVE_STORAGE_BLOB` already exists in that schema.

What to do? First find out what it really is by querying

```
select * from user_objects where object_name = 'ACTIVE_STORAGE_BLOB';
```

Then decide what to do:

- maybe you'll do *nothing* and continue using existing object
- maybe you'll have to rename table you're trying to create. Or,
- maybe you'll drop existing object so that you could create the table.

It depends on what you'll find out.

Comment: I just want to know why its happen but the migration already ran.

Comment: Why happen what? Error happened because object with that name already exists, and you can't have two objects in the same schema with the same name.

Comment: yes you are right to object is present with the same name in the schema, but My question is why it's happening again because I already run all the migrations. after updating ruby from 5.1 to 5.2 and then running Rspec get migration missing error and then run migration command got this error.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Ruby nor Rspec nor "migration" you do. I just answered your question about ORA-00955.